# Google App Engine; is it possible to change scaling configuration at runtime without redeploying the app?

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-module

For applications deployed on `Google App Engine`, is it possible to change the scaling configuration at runtime without redeploying the app?

Changing the `appengine-web.xml` and redeploying is an option, however was wondering if this can be done through the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it not possible at this time to change the scaling configuration of your `appengine-web.xml` or `app.yaml` without redeploying the module/service.

The most control over scaling one can have at runtime is with the [ModulesService](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/modules/ModulesService.html).  With this, one can determine the number of instances currently running of a given module-version and can start/stop a given module-version using the [`startVersion`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/modules/ModulesService.html#method-detail) and [`stopVersion`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/modules/ModulesService.html#method-detail) methods.  Though quite limited, you are granted some control.

If `appengine-web.xml`/`app.yaml` configuration at runtime is a feature you would like to see implemented,  feel free to file a feature request on the [App Engine public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) provided a thorough business case.